# as3 - addchild with drag and drop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to add a child instance of an object to the stage, then allow the user to drag and drop this object (in this case, a movie clip) on the stage. However, I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at working_copy_fla::MainTimeline/dragObject()

So, that is my first problem. Then second problem, is I have not found an answer as to how to make a child object (specifically, a movie clip) able to properly be dragged and dropped on the stage.

Here is my code:

```
// Allow buttons to bring objects to the stage
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addImage);

function addImage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var myImage:Image_mc = new Image_mc();
    stage.addChild(myImage);
    // Center the object
    myImage.x = 300;
    myImage.y = 300;


    // Allow the object to be drag and dropped  
    myImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
    myImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
}

function startDragging(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.x = event.target.parent.mouseX - event.target.mouseX
    event.target.y = event.target.parent.mouseY - event.target.mouseY

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragObject);
}

function dragObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.x = event.target.parent.mouseX - event.target.mouseX
    event.target.y = event.target.parent.mouseY - event.target.mouseY
}

function stopDragging(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragObject);
}
```

**EDIT**

I figured it out, and the solution was as simple as looking to the sample code in Adobe Flash (using CS6). Here is my code now:

```
// Allow buttons to bring objects to the stage
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addImage);

function addImage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var myImage:Image_mc = new Image_mc();
    stage.addChild(myImage);
    // Center the object
    myImage.x = 300;
    myImage.y = 300;


    // Allow the object to be dragged
    myImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickToDrag);
}

function clickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.startDrag();
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseToDrop);

function releaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.stopDrag();
}
```

The key here was that I have created universal functions (clickToDrag and releaseToDrop) that will accept input from any object (so I can re-use these functions with other images that I add to the stage). This code works with multiple children on the stage (all can be drag and dropped at any time).

The only problem I am having with it now is that I am getting this error whenever I spawn a child element (by clicking on the *myButton* button instance):

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property stopDrag not found on flash.display.SimpleButton and there is no default value.
    at working_copy_fla::MainTimeline/releaseToDrop()
```

This error is not stopping the application from working; everything still runs fine. But I would still like to figure out why this error is occuring. My guess is that whatever is using "stopDrag" (should just be a movie clip) is not capable of that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have finally figured it out. The key was not to add an event to the stage, but rather, to add the "releaseToDrop" function to the  *MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP* event on the child element in the same function that adds it to the stage. Now I get no more errors, and it works with multiple instances of the child objects (movie clips) on the stage.

Here is the code that works:

```
// Allow buttons to bring objects to the stage
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addImage);

function addImage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var myImage:Image_mc = new Image_mc();
    stage.addChild(myImage);
    // Center the object
    myImage.x = 300;
    myImage.y = 300;


    // Allow the object to be dragged
    myImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickToDrag);
    myImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseToDrop);
}

function clickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.startDrag();
}

function releaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.stopDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
event.target.x = event.target.parent.mouseX - event.target.mouseX
```

The above code assumes that 'event.target' is the stage, right (because you added the listener to the stage)? So you're trying to change the x/y of the stage? No.  The start/stopDragging should make a reference to the object being dragged, available as a private class variable,  which is visible to the dragObject method.  Also, what is the stage's parent ('event.target.parent.mouseX')?  There is no parent to the stage.  This is probably what the "null object reference" is refering to.

*EDIT*

I'm used to Object-Oriented AS3 (highly recommended), but I'm guessing that programming on the 'timeline' the following should work. Declare a variable outside of your functions, something like:

`var objectCurrentDragging:DisplayObjectContainer;`

Then in your 'addImage' function, use the following code to make objectCurrentDragging reference the object which you want to drag:

```
objectCurrentDragging = myImage;
```

Then in the dragObject function, simply reference objectCurrentDragging:

```
objectCurrentDragging.x = ...
```

Hope that works out for you.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you're saying. But how would I make the "dragObject" and "stopDragging" functions universal so that any child object created can use them to be dragged and dropped?

Comment: I actually figured out a solution, but I am getting a non-critical error when I execute the code. It doesn't stop working, but I still get the error.

Comment: And I have now found the solution to the problem. In the future, I am going to learn object-oriented actionscript programming, as timeline scripting just seems very archaic. It works for small projects, but it definitely does not scale very well. Thank you for your help, @hunter.